# Beginner Swift 3 Data Validation

Tags: swift, validation

Swift newbie here trying to setup a data validation function, but my code generates the following error:  "Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two 'Double?' operands"

```
func validateDouble(text: String) -> Bool {
    var result = false

    // test input to see if it is a positive Double once text is converted
    if Double(text) > 0.0 {
        result = true
    }
}
```

I'm stumped and would appreciate any kind assistance.

Thanks,

Nas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when you convert string to Double type it return optional value, so it may be nil or not. that's why comparison with exact value is not possible. Try like this way.

```
func validateDouble(text: String) -> Bool {
    var result = false

    // test input to see if it is a positive Double once text is converted
    if let doubleValue = Double(text) {
      if doubleValue > 0.0 {
        result = true
      }
   }   
}
```

Comment: Wow--appreciate the super rapid answer!!! I was going to deal with the nil possibility later, but I am seeing that delaying dealing with nil is not a workable strategy in swift.  Thank you so much--you answer works perfect!

Comment: @Nas Welcome, You said that your are newbie in swift, that's why I elaborate  this answer with long way, otherwise it can also be done with short way. If you want to know

Comment: @Jaydeep, you can also modify your if condtion using where clause(ie using ',') that is like more swift feature. for instance (if let doubleValue = Double(text),  doubleValue > 0.0 {})

Answer (score 1):

You need to check make sure the converted value is not nil, this should do the trick:

```
func validateDouble(text: String) -> Bool {

    // test input to see if it is a positive Double once text is converted
    guard let value = Double(text), value > 0.0 else { return false }
    return true

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if let doubleValue = Double(text), doubleValue > 0.0 {
  result = true
}
```